# Passing JRadioSelection to an ActionLIstener class

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton, buttongroup

For my application,  I created two `JRadioButton` grouped into a "selection" `ButtonGroup`. I added an `ActionListener` called "SelectionListener." When I check if my `RadioButton` is selected using `isSelected()`, it appears that my selection is not getting passed over to the `ActionListener`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JRadioButton monthlyRadioButton = new JRadioButton("Monthly Payment", true);
    JRadioButton loanAmountButton = new JRadioButton("Loan Amount");
    ButtonGroup selection = new ButtonGroup();
    selection.add(monthlyRadioButton);
    selection.add(loanAmountButton);
    monthlyRadioButton.addActionListener(new SelectionListener());
    loanAmountButton.addActionListener(new SelectionListener());
}
```

SelectionListener.java

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

class SelectionListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
      if(event.getSource() == monthlyRadioButton)
        System.out.println("You clicked Monthly");
      else
        System.out.println("You clicked Loan Amount");

    }
}
```

The parameters `monthlyRadioButton` is not getting passed over to my `SelectionListener` class. I'm getting an error that it is not being resolved.

**How do I pass the `monthlyRadioButton` in my main method over to my `SelectionListener` class?**

Comment: For future reference, you should include the exact error message in your question. I read the whole thing and it was never clear that you have a compiler error here. Including this information will help us answer your questions faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You car retrieve the sender of the event is being handled.

Something like:

```
class SelectionListener implements ActionListener {
    private JComponent monthlyRadioButton;
    private JComponent loanAmountButton;

    public SelectionListener(JComponent monthlyRadioButton, JComponent loanAmountButton) {
        this.monthlyRadioButton = monthlyRadioButton;
        this.loanAmountButton = loanAmountButton;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        if(event.getSource() == monthlyRadioButton)
            System.out.println("You clicked Monthly");
        else if(event.getSource() == loanAmountButton)
            System.out.println("You clicked Loan Amount");
    }
}
```

On your main method you could instantiate it like:

```
    monthlyRadioButton.addActionListener(new SelectionListener(monthlyRadioButton, loanAmountButton));
```

Comment: I tried this, but my monthlyRadioButton and loanAmountButton is giving me an error saying that those two cannot be resolved.

Comment: Money... Stackoverflow points for you! Thanks for the help, Spaeth.

Answer (score 1):

You create a new variable in `main` named `monthlyRadioButton` (thius is local to `main`, not visible from anywhere else), but check another (not listed in your code) in `actionPerformed`

Comment: I moved it outside of my main method, but I'm still getting the same problem.    
`public static JRadioButton monthlyRadioButton = new JRadioButton("Monthly Payment", true);`

`public static JRadioButton loanAmountButton = new JRadioButton("Loan Amount");`

Answer (score 1):

The `actionListeners` registered on `JRadioButton` are called before the radio button becomes selected. That is why your `isSelected()` invocations return `false` (or to be more precise: they return the actual value, before the change).

If you want to handle state changes, you should register a [`ChangeListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addChangeListener%28javax.swing.event.ChangeListener%29).